# Ubuntu MATE, Cinnamon Desktop, custom icon set does not scale

Tags: 16.04, icons, mate, cinnamon

I have quite a strange problem with any custom icon set under Ubuntu 16.04 MATE with Cinnamon Desktop

On a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 MATE version I did

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon*
sudo apt-get purge mate*
```

Everything works perfectly. Now download any custom icon set. I tried all of them: [here](http://linuxmint-art.org/content/show.php/Black+Diamond+Icons?content=174473) and [here](http://linuxmint-art.org/content/show.php/Mashup+Five?content=95717)

The custom icons are all svgs.

I encounter the same effect on all of them:

- Install as they describe (basically move to `/usr/share/icons`)
- set the icons via "themes" setting
- Nautilus AND nemo are not able to scale these icons and only show maximum size

Interesting part: I have a machine running Linux mint 17.3 where these Icons work absolutely perfectly and as expected, so the problem needs to be somewhere on my system, not with the icons.

Furthermore, I CANNOT resize the icons on the desktop (when I right click -> resize icon: a border appears but does not move at all when dragged), but the icons do resize when switching from icon view to list view in any file browser and are scaling when zooming in this view.

When I use the default icons, everything works as expected.

**What I've tried so far**

- download dconf-editor and tweak around at `/org/gnome/nautilus/list/view`
- reinstall nemo and nautilus (also tried `nautilus --force-desktop` which does change my background but does not solve the problem)
- cleared `~/.thumbnails` and `~/.cache/thumbnails` (which do not contain these icons in any form at all)

What else can I try?